# Router is undefined in @injectable Class

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router

For some reason `router` is undefined in my Class, could someone please shed some light on this?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { XHRBackend, RequestOptions, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthApiService extends ApiService {
    constructor (
        private auth: AuthService,
        public router: Router,
        backend: XHRBackend,
        options: RequestOptions,
   ) {
       super(router, backend, options);
       const token = this.auth.getToken();
       options.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
   }

   public handleError(error: Response) {
       super.handleError(error);

       console.log(this.router); // <- undefined

       return Observable.throw(error);
   }
}
```

**API Class**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, XHRBackend, RequestOptions, Request, RequestOptionsArgs, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class ApiService extends Http {
  constructor (
    public router: Router,
    backend: XHRBackend,
    options: RequestOptions
  ) {
    super(backend, options);
  }

  public request(url: string|Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs):     Observable<Response> {
    return super.request(url, options).catch(this.handleError);
  }

  public handleError(error: Response) {
    return Observable.throw(error);
  }
```

}

Comment: Who is calling handleError? Some AJAX function? You won't have a reference to the correct scope using `this` if it's in the wrong scope, unless you're using fat arrow syntax.

Comment: Maybe you did not import the `RouterModule` module ?

Comment: Can you add the module in which this service is declared in the 'providers' array?

Comment: My other API Class is calling handleError.

Comment: I've added my default API Class to OP.

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri I have the `RouterModule` present in the imports array of my app.module. The Router works in other places, just not in this scenario.

Comment: I fixed it by using a factory for `ApiService` and adding `Router` as a dependency.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue today. The problem is that: inside the function `handleError`, 'this' is not pointed to `AuthApiService` but a new context. You need to modify your `handleError` function like this:

```
public handleError(self){
    return (error: Response) => {
        super.handleError(error); 
        console.log(self.router);

        return Observable.throw(error);
    }
}
```

call this function by passing in a reference to 
AuthApiService`.catch(this.handleError(this))`